# Is it possible to use Cororna communicating with server via UDP/TCP/IP Protocol

Tags: coronasdk

I have a project needs to communiction with server via UDP/TCP/IP protocol
The client side I will use Corona sdk, 
but I am not sure if Corona support UDP/TCP communication, or I need to make the function by myself?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try page 64 of the API reference here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.anscamobile.com%2Fdemo%2FAPIReference.pdf&rct=j&q=carona%20sdk%20api&ei=Rh6RTcnUGY2WsgPQqfmnDg&usg=AFQjCNGqduQgly1eTfPV2KHGv2nbYeC4Yg

It redirects to the "socket reference" here: http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/reference.html

This talks about everything you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Corona SDK includes the luasocket module which supports low level socket support.  It's hard to tell because it's not listed in the API reference (http://developer.anscamobile.com/resources/apis/) but there is a short discussion here (http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/network)